# Is it possible/practical to use Lua's hash table outside of Lua?

Tags: c, lua, hashtable

I find myself needing a hash table container in a C project which includes Lua.  I am wondering if it is possible to use the hash table in Lua as a generic container.  I have looked at `ltable.h` and all of the functions require a Lua state and seem tied to the Lua environment so I am guessing this is not practical if the data needs to be independent of Lua.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible and the easiest way is just to use the official C API for Lua. No need to dig into the innards of ltable.h.

Answer (score 0):

You can use luabind or luabridge to specify how a C++ hash (say stl's map) will be represented in Lua; then you'll be able to pass it to the Lua engine. Note that any usage of Lua will require to pass the Lua state, no escape here.

Comment: The source in question is pure c not c++ so no STL <map> otherwise I would just use that

Comment: Ok, use the lua API then. Sorry.